# Entity Framework 4.0: Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role

Tags: entity-framework

I have put a new table in my database and there are 4 tables that have a foreign key relationship with it.
I thought I configured all 4 in the same way, but I get this error;

> Error 15  Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ReportCellImage' in relationship 'FK_OtherLeaves_ReportCellImages'. Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '0..1'.

So to simplify my tables;

ReportCellImage table contains the
ReportCellImageId field which in the primary key and an integer

OtherLeave table contains the 
ReportCellImageId field as a nullable foreign key with a default of 4

The other tables are similar and all have a foreign key configured to join with the ReportCellImage table

This is a recent change, so when I update my edmx file from the database, why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If your FK is nullable your multiplicity in principal entity must be 0..1 - default value has no role in this because you can assign null to FK. So all your dependent entities must be in 0..1 - * relation with your principal entity.

Comment: what I really want is a 1 to many relationship. The field is better if it is not nullable. Howevever then I cannot deploy the changes to the existing database because of the foreign key constraint. BTW I am not a dba and if I was I would probably know how to do this easily.

Comment: EF will not allow you doing that. If your field is nullable you cannot have 1 to many. You must use 0..1 to many.

Comment: What I have found is that if I want a new non-nullable field on my table, I need first to create it as a nullable field and populate it. Then I can make it non-nullable. I then have to take the same steps when deploying to live. I wonder if there is a better way? Anyway when doing all this and updating EF from the database the settings in EF do not always match the database changes and hence I get this kind of bug. Technically your answers are correct so I will give you a tick.

Comment: Can anyone clarify what I can and can't change in this thing? If I change properties of the relationship (derived from the foreign key in the database) won't the next refresh just overwrite them and reproduce the error? What I found was that existing tables with NULLable FK fields were OK but the one table with a non-nullable FK caused this error. Why on earth would a _stronger_ constraint in the DB cause such an issue for EDMX?

Comment: This helped me discover that I needed to mark my FK properties as nullable.

Answer (score 72):

I just had the same message and it was perplexing because the tables I modified in the DB were different from the ones I was getting the message for.

I tried changing the multiplicity 0..1-to-many but the message persisted, even after "Run Custom Tool" commands, cleans and rebuilds.

Resolved by dropping the relationship EF was complaining about and updating the model from DB

Comment: This is unfortunate, but often seems to be the case with EF. You can spend ages trying to work out what you've done wrong, only to finish by concluding that it wasn't you :(

Comment: Sometimes simply closing and re-opening the solution can make these errors disappear.

Comment: Still works. The 'refresh model from database' (EF 6.1.3) doesn't update relations in the right way. This solution saves time. Thank you.

Comment: EF + <any problem> = delete and recreate

Answer (score 17):

Right click on the relationship in your EDX diagrame.
In proprety, change END1 Multiplicity to 0..1 (Zero or One of YOURTABLENAME)

Comment: Right answer - but IMO it's easier to do from the database model browser in the "Associations" section than in the diagram.

Answer (score 7):

I deleted the updated table from the model and then in Update Model from Database, added it again and it helped.

Comment: that fixed it for me

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a database first approach to create the .edmx file.  When I ran into this issue, I tried a couple of the suggestions above, but was still getting errors, so I deleted the .edmx file and refreshed the entire file from the updated database.

I've found that sometimes EF gets confused after updates to the existing database, and while it's ideal to find the root cause, spending an hour working on something may not be possible in a work environment (such as mine)

Our DB is new and small so refreshing the file is easy and doesn't take that long.
Problem went away, moving on . . .

Answer (score 5):

It is asking you to change the Principal Role to 0..1 not the entire relationship so that the relation ship becomes 0-1 to Many.

1. Right click on the relationship line in the edmx graph
2. Select properties
3. Change End1Multiplicity (ReportCellImages) from 1 to 0..1
4. Rebuild

Comment: Nice answer, but it's easier to do from the database model browser in the "Associations" section than in the diagram

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after adding a new table, I tried all the solutions here including dropping the relationship, but that didn't work. The solution that worked for me was to actually delete the model completely and create a new model. Don't forget to delete the connection string in the web.config so that your new EF will be able to use the same name.

Comment: what if you have a huge database? I would imagine you could use EF code first Model first, but it would still be a pretty big deal to remove and add a large database.

Answer (score 2):

This error is mainly because the table definitions might have changed after adding to the EF.
The solution is to delete it from EF Model and add again using update model from database.

Answer (score 1):

> Change Multiplicity="1" to Multiplicity="0..1"

```
 <Association Name="FK_O_Personel_PBS_AtanmaSekilleri">
          <End Type="eKampus_RTEUModel.PBS_AtanmaSekilleri" Role="PBS_AtanmaSekilleri" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <End Type="eKampus_RTEUModel.O_Personel" Role="O_Personel" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="PBS_AtanmaSekilleri">
              <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="O_Personel">
              <PropertyRef Name="atamaSekliID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the Entity reference in the entity classes then removing the reference manually in the database, then putting them back step by step to resolve the issue I realized after I finished the quick solution would have been to replace the WithOptional with WithRequired in the Context after I first changed the field from nullable to non nullable.

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`