# Entity Framework 1 to 1 relationship using code first. how?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes.  How can I turn these two classes into a one to one relationship using the entity framework code first method?

```
public class Region
{
  public int RegionId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual Factory _factory { get; set; }
}

public class Factory
{
  public int FactoryId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual Region _region { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this, I get this error:
Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Region_Factory_Source' in relationship 'Region_Factory'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: [Entity Framework 4.0: Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292738/entity-framework-4-0-error-113-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This occurs in CodeFirst because of the virtual keyword.  In effect, you are creating a relationship where creating one item requires the creation of the other.  however, the virtual keyword allows lazy instantiation, which means that creating an object of one type doesn't automatically create the other type, allowing the Id on the foreign item to be null.  This implies a 0..1 relationship, but since each side is virtual, what you get is a 0..0 which isn't allowed.

There are 2 methods which you can use to remedy the situation.

1. remove the virtual option from either one side or both sides of the navigation properties, allowing for a 0..1 or a 1..1 map.
2. explicitly add a property for the Foreign key from the other entity on each object.  i.e. on class `Region` add a property for `FactoryId` and on `Factory` add a property for `RegionId`

There are other ways to help Entity Framework determine which object is the Dependent Object, i.e. using Entity Framework Fluent api.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired)

> Configuring a Relationship Where Both Ends Are Required (One-to-One)
>
> In most cases the Entity Framework can infer which type is the dependent and which is the principal in a relationship. However, when both ends of the relationship are required or both sides are optional the Entity Framework cannot identify the dependent and principal. When both ends of the relationship are required, use WithRequiredPrincipal or WithRequiredDependent after the HasRequired method. When both ends of the relationship are optional, use WithOptionalPrincipal or WithOptionalDependent after the HasOptional method.

the following code would create a Principal `Factory` with a Dependent `Region`

```
// Configure the primary key for the Region
modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
    .HasKey(t => t.RegionId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Factory>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Region)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Factory);
```

Comment: Confusing, the virtual keyword, according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi should have no effect on relationships.

Comment: That MSDN excerpt helped!

Comment: I suspect that the time has run its course and invalidated parts of the answer (not your fault, of course, hehe). As of EF6 (and possibly EF5, not sure about that), one can't do that anymore. I just tested that for one of my students (explicit foreign key attributes on both, dropping virtual on each at the time and on both). No cookies, though... I guess FluidApi is the only way to go, unless one questions the validity of 1:1 relations (considering putting both entities into the same table). What do you think? Can you confirm/dement my comment, please?

Answer (score 5):

EF6, add attributes:

```
[Key]
public int RegionId { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("Region")]
public int FactoryId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution create a composite key?