# MVC 5 - Can't save entity in one to one relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to create a one to one relationship between two entities using EF, however when I try to actually create the `CumulativeRecord` entity I get this error on `db.SaveChanges()`:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CumulativeRecords' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

My two models are as follows:

```
public class CumulativeRecord
{
    [ForeignKey("ANA")]
    public int CumulativeRecordId { get; set; }
    public virtual ANA ANA { get; set; }
}

public class ANA
{
    public int ANAId { get; set; }
    public virtual CumulativeRecord CumulativeRecord { get; set; }
}
```

and using the Fluent API I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ANA>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.CumulativeRecord)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.ANA);
}
```

Despite this setup, I am unable to save a new `CumulativeRecord` object.

This is my current attempt at saving the object:

```
var experience = new CumulativeRecord { ANA = newANA };
db.CumulativeRecords.Add(experience);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It is also worth noting that I am not working with a new database, this database exists and I am adding models and relationships to it.

Comment: Have you tried setting making `CumulativeRecordId` a primary key to the table `CumulativeRecord` ? EF can't do updates on tables without a primary key.

Comment: CumulativeRecordId is the primary key by default, if you follow convention. However I will try adding a `[Key]` anyway

Answer (score 0):

The error answers the question. You are trying to insert a specific value into the `CumulativeRecordId` field, but in the database this is the primary key of the `CumulativeRecord` table.

It's set as `IDENTIY` which means that it will auto-increment, so you should never need to insert a value in this column.

Also, as it's a 1 - 1 relationship you need foreign keys on both sides of the relationship as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724964/entity-framework-1-to-1-relationship-using-code-first-how).

Your classes should look as follows

```
public class CumulativeRecord
{
    public int CumulativeRecordId { get; set; }

    public int AnaRecordId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AnaRecordId")]
    public virtual ANA ANA { get; set; }
}

public class ANA
{
    public int ANAId { get; set; }

    public int CumulativeRecordId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CumulativeRecordId")]
    public virtual CumulativeRecord CumulativeRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See my updated attempt at saving the object, i'm not trying to insert a key manually, at least I don't think I am.

Comment: Modified my answer slightly. Have you defined your foreign key as above?

Comment: getting a new error by doing things this way, `ANA_CumulativeRecord_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ANA_CumulativeRecord_Target' in relationship 'ANA_CumulativeRecord'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'`

Comment: @barnacle.m Have a look at my changes now. You need foreign keys on both sides of the relationship if it's 1 - 1 apparently. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724964/entity-framework-1-to-1-relationship-using-code-first-how. I have this working locally.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I should modify in my context class using Fluent?

Comment: I didn't change anything if that's what you're asking, but otherwise I don't see a problem.

Comment: `ANA` should *not* have a foreign key to `CumulativeRecordId` and `CumulativeRecord` no `AnaRecordId`. `CumulativeRecordId` as both primary key and foreign key is enough for required 1:1 associations.

Comment: @GertArnold as per the link I included that was one of the options, and if a foreign key exists in one it needs to exist in the other. I did try removing the foreign keys and removing virtual from the navigation properties and this worked for me also.

Comment: @barnacle.m if this answer works for you, please remember to accept it as the answer to the question.