# EF model multiplicity relationship error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Model with two tables:  `Version` and `GeneralInformation`.

Here's my `Version` table:

```
Version
-----------
VersionID - PK
OwnerID
VersionParentID
isLocked
```

And my `GeneralInformation` table:

```
GeneralInformation
-----------
GeneralInformationID - PK
VersionID
FirstName
LastName
StoreName
MemberNumber
```

**Here is my current relationship:**

```
Foreign Key Base Table:  GeneralInformation (dbo)
Foreign Key Columns:     VersionID
Primary Key Table:       Version
Primary Key Columns:     VersionID
```

My goal is to have 1 GeneralInformation row for a particular `VersionID`.  But EF seems to be attempting to create many GeneralInformation for a `VersionID`.

When I update the Model in Entity Framework, it creates `* (Collection of GeneralInformation)` for `End2 Multiplicity`.  However, it should be 1 to 1 relationship.  Not 1 to Many.  When I change it to `0..1 (Zero or One of GeneralInformation)` it gives me an error:

> Error  1   Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'GeneralInformation' in relationship 'FK_GeneralInformation_Version'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

**What am I doing wrong?  Your help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: I made the `VersionID` of `GeneralInformation` a PK, instead of `GeneralInformationID` and it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Is the foreign key "VersionID" in the General Information table defined as a Unique value?

For instance

```
GeneralInformation
-----------
GeneralInformationID - PK
VersionID - UNIQUE
FirstName
LastName
StoreName
MemberNumber
```

This seems to be related in the sense that the [EF Model Multiplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292738/entity-framework-4-0-error-113-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role)

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: Is the value nullable?

Comment: The `VersionID` is `(int, not null)`