# EntityTypeConfiguration validation errors

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having issue with mapping these entities.  I am sort of new to this so I am not sure where I'm messing up.  Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error:
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Recipe_RecipeIngredients_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Recipe_RecipeIngredients_Source' in relationship 'Recipe_RecipeIngredients'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Here is the diagram of the two tables I have

[image: recipe]

And I have the mapping code as follows:

```
public class RecipeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Recipe>
{
    public RecipeMap()
    {
        HasKey(g => g.RecipeId);
        ToTable("recipes");
        Property(g => g.RecipeId).HasColumnName("RecipeId");
        Property(g => g.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        Property(g => g.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
        Property(g => g.IsOnMenu).HasColumnName("IsOnMenu");
        Property(g => g.Url).HasColumnName("Url");
        Property(g => g.ImagePath).HasColumnName("ImagePath");
        Property(g => g.Calories).HasColumnName("Calories");
        Property(g => g.Servings).HasColumnName("Servings");
        Property(g => g.TotalTime).HasColumnName("TotalTime");
        Property(g => g.PrepTime).HasColumnName("PrepTime");
        Property(g => g.CookTime).HasColumnName("CookTime");
        this.HasRequired(g => g.RecipeIngredients).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipeId);

    }
}

public class RecipeIngredientMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<RecipeIngredient>
{
    public RecipeIngredientMap()
    {
        HasKey(g => g.IngredientId);
        ToTable("recipeIngredient");
        Property(g => g.RecipeId).HasColumnName("RecipeId").IsRequired();
        Property(g => g.IngredientName).HasColumnName("IngredientName");
        Property(g => g.Quantity).HasColumnName("Quantity");
        Property(g => g.Category).HasColumnName("Category");
        Property(g => g.IsOnMenu).HasColumnName("IsOnMenu");
        //this.HasRequired(g => g.Recipe);
    }
}

 public class RecipeContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RecipeMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RecipeIngredientMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue, is there an error of some kind, or is the data not populated as you'd expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292738/entity-framework-4-0-error-113-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role

Comment: Even if I just take out the HasRequired for recipeIngredients I don't get the error but then there is nothing when I call the context.RecipeIngredients.ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with Entity Framework for a while, so this might not be strictly correct.

I'm assuming your classes look something like this:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // Other code

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    // Other code
}
```

I think the relationship you're trying to describe (I may be incorrect) is that a `Recipe` has many `Ingredients`, so I'd try this in your `RecipeMap` (using your own property names):

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Ingredients) // A Recipe has many ingredients.
    .WithRequired() // Ingredient requires a recipe.
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipeID); // Our Foreign Key on Ingredient.
```

As a slight aside, it seems like your data model could be further normalised by introducing a junction/link table e.g `RecipeIngredients` (or converting the one you already have), containing the fields `RecipeID` and `IngredientID`, `Quantity`.

You could then extract all the fields which relate specifically to an `Ingredient` into an `Ingredients` table, and save some ingredient data duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the help man.  I really appreciate it.  Once I remembered I changed the name of my connection string this worked PERFECT.  I'm really challenging myself to learn this side of things and I feel like I'm actually learning quite a bit.  But sometimes I get so lost its nice that Stackoverflow exists.

Comment: Glad it helped, I'm a little rusty on this topic, but when I was manually configuring mappings using fluent syntax, I found it helpful to try and describe the relationship like in the above code / reading it out loud. This HasMany of these, which Require one of these etc. Also worth playing with the overloads e.g. `WithRequired` can accept a `Func` which allows for a `Recipe` navigation property on the `RecipeIngredient` if required. Good luck =D

Answer (score 1):

One Recipe has multiple ingredient , as per that it seems you have implied wrong relationship in mapping.

Remove hasRequired from RecipeMap() and add following to the RecipeIngredientMap() instead

```
 this.HasRequired(g => g.Recipes)
.WithMany(y => y.RecipesIngredient)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipeId);
```

Comment: That won't compile.  Something like this? 
this.HasRequired(g => g.Recipe).WithMany(x => x.RecipeIngredients).HasForeignKey(y => y.RecipeId);  However I still get nothing from the context when I do Context.Recipes.ToList() so I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: make sure your class looks like what @Chris suggested and that change you made is correct my bad..