# EF Code First not setting foreign key in one to one relationship

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

So I'm trying to create a simple Product-Preview 1 to 1 relationship as follows:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual EPS eps { get; set; }
    public virtual Preview preview { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
    public Guid userId { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Preview : BaseEntity
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("Product")]        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TextPreview> Texts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ImagePlaceHolder> ImagePlaceHolders { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting to have a foreign key in the Previews table that would point to a Product
but after running the migration I just get it as regular field

[image]

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it you just missed one piece of the puzzle ...

```
[ForeignKey("ProductId")]
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

You also need to add ...

```
public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
```

to the preview object.

It's also worth noting that the ForeignKey attrib can be put on either property, and the string must refer to the other one of the pair.

As it's currently written you are trying to make the Id property specify the value for both the primary key and the foreign key on the tables in question.

So your final code might look something like ...

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual EPS eps { get; set; }
    public virtual Preview preview { get; set; }
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Preview : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public string imagePath { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TextPreview> Texts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ImagePlaceHolder> ImagePlaceHolders { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

As a side note I would also recommend against using concrete collection types like `List<T>` instead use something like `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` it promotes better code reuse and extensibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I follow your suggestion I end up having this error:  Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Preview_product_Source' in relationship 'Preview_product'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: That's this problem solved and you now have a different problem which is explained here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292738/entity-framework-4-0-error-113-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role

Comment: Essentially you have a 1 to 1 relationship and it seems like the issue may be that what you want is a 0-1 to 1 relationship ... making the guid ProductId nullable "Guid?" may fix this.