# CS2034 Error The type or namespace name 'DataAccessLayer' does not exist in ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.9 project in VS2019 using Entity Framework 6 and running on .NET 4.5.2.

Everything has been working fine until recently when I did a minor "Update Model From Database", then I get the following error (x 45 files)....

> Error CS0234
> The type or namespace name 'DataAccessLayer' does not exist in the namespace 'CPPE.Hubble' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have made no changes, updates etc.

I have tried deleting contents in the `obj` folder, running the "Custom Tool" on the `.tt` file, checked the build order and dependencies, cleaned and rebuild individual projects.

It basically cannot see a whole project `Hubble.DataAccessLayer` (greyed out below):

[image]

[image]

Project `Business Logic` depends on `DataAccessLayer`.

Comment: Global search `DataAccessLayer` or `DataAccessLayer.Model`, do you still have the namespace defined in DataAccessLayer project?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'defined' in this case but when I search from th emenu bar or in the solution seacrch box it appears several times

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have fixed it.
The issue was with a constraint in the edmx file.
I was getting a '113 Multiplicity error' in the end role element on a one particular table.  Don't know how this came about.  I can only think that somebody has made a change in the database without me knowing?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292738/entity-framework-4-0-error-113-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role#:%7E:text=This%20error%20is%20mainly%20because,using%20update%20model%20from%20database.) post helped